# Are Lusin and Souslin spaces sequential or even Fréchet-Urysohn?

Tags: general-topology, convergence-divergence, topological-vector-spaces, descriptive-set-theory, locally-convex-spaces

First some definitions:

- A Polish space is a separable and completely metrizable topological space.
- A Hausdorff space is Lusin if it is the image of a Polish space under a bijective continuous map.
- A Hausdorff space is Souslin if it is the image of a Polish space under a continuous map.
- A topological space is sequential if every sequentially closed set is closed.
- A sequential space is Fréchet-Urysohn if the sequential closure of every subset is sequentially closed (and thus closed).

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_space#Lusin_spaces) says that
"A Lusin space is a topological space such that some weaker topology makes it into a Polish space."

So I think this is wrong and should be restated as:
"A Lusin space is a HAUSDORFF space such that some STRONGER topology makes it into a Polish space."

Similar for Souslin spaces in the Wikipedia article where the Hausdorff property for Souslin spaces should be added.

Now for the main questions:

1. Is every Lusin space Fréchet-Urysohn or at least sequential?
2. What about the larger set of Souslin spaces? Are these Fréchet-Urysohn or at least sequential?

If 1. or 2. is wrong what about the special type of such spaces that arise in functional analysis as locally convex spaces that are countable locally convex inductive or projective limits of Fréchet or Banach spaces and their weak* duals?

Comment: 1. is  obviously wrong because there are countable (perfectly normal) spaces which are not sequential, see, for instance, Example 1.6.20 from  Engelking’s “General Topology”.

Comment: But sequential spaces are preserved by quotient maps and Fréchet-Urysohn spaces are preserved by hereditarily  quotient maps (ibid., Ex. 2.4.G).

Comment: Concerning the special type of spaces: what about $\Bbb R^\infty=\lim_{\to} \Bbb R^n$?

Comment: And each locally convex topological vector spaces is sequential?

Comment: It seems no, because Tychonov powers of $\Bbb R$ are universal for Tychonov spaces, sequentiality is preserved by closed subspases, Fréchet-Urysohn property is preserved by any subspaces (ibid., Ex. 2.1.H),  and there are non-sequential compacts (for instance, $\beta N$ (ibid., Cor. 3.6.16))

Comment: Sorry, I meant locally convex spaces that are countable locally convex inductive limits of Fréchet spaces or Banach spaces and their weak* duals. I correct the question. Also thanks for the counterexample of a countable non-sequential Hausdorff space.

Comment: I am not very acquainted with [direct limits of topological vector spaces](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/382792/direct-inductive-limit-of-locally-convex-tves-and-universal-property), so the following ideas may be naive. If an inductive limit of a family of sequential (Fréchet-Urysohn) (topological vector) spaces is a natural quotient of their disjoint sum,  it is sequential (similarly with hereditary quotient).

Comment: Another way to show the sequentiality of the direct limit $X$ of a family $\{X_\alpha\}$ of sequential  (topological vector) spaces may be the following. Suppose that  $A$ is not closed subset of $X$. Then there exists a space $X_\alpha$ such that a set $A\cap X_\alpha$ is not closed in a space $X_\alpha$ (for the sake of simplicity we consider $X=\bigcup X_\alpha$). Then it is not sequentially closed in $X_\alpha$, so there is a sequence $\{x_n\}$ of points of the space  $A\cap X_\alpha$ converging to a point $x\in X_\alpha\setminus A$.

Comment: Then $x\in X\setminus A$ and the sequence $\{x_n\}$ witnesses that the set $A$ is not sequentially closed in the space $X$.

Comment: Ok, clear. So it remains to analyze whether such locally convex inductive limits of Fréchet (or Banach) spaces are Fréchet-Urysohn and in addition whether their weak-* duals are sequential (or even Fréchet-Urysohn). Recall that the weak-* dual of the inductive limit is the projective limit of the weak-* duals.